# Build error when installing bip32 on Azure node.js service

Tags: node.js, azure, npm

I'm trying to deploy a `node.js` app on `Azure`. Simply moving the `node-modules` from my mac and running the `url` results in

```
Error: \\?\D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\scrypt\build\Release\scrypt.node is not a valid Win32 application.
```

So I decided to install the nodules directly on the machine. I `ssh'd` to it and started installing packages. A couple worked well but when attempting to install `bip32` it fails with the following stack.

Any ideas?

```
D:\home\site\wwwroot
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\6.1.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:237:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\10.6.0\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\6.1.0\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node- 
gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\tiny-secp256k1
gyp ERR! node -v v10.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN Invalid version: "0.2"
npm WARN wwwroot No description
npm WARN wwwroot No repository field.
npm WARN wwwroot No README data
npm WARN wwwroot No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tiny-secp256k1@1.0.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the tiny-secp256k1@1.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-11T12_02_52_844Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score -1):

Your build fails because it can not build the `tiny-secp256k1` module, which requires [secp256k1](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1) native C module.

Solution could be to use [secp256k1-node](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/secp256k1-node#installation) npm module instead. Take a look the windows specific installation notes in the linked repo.

Or simply install the required [secp256k1](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1) native C dependency.

Comment: `tiny-secp256k1` is installed as part of the `bip32` install, which obviously is out of my control. So I can't use your solution.

Comment: You asked for the reason, not for the solution. But I edited my answer :)

Comment: This is supposed to be a managed service. Having to install packages myself is really not inspiring confidence. Anyway. Which type of machine do I get, when creating the Web App? I moved the entire node-modules folder from another windows machine, but I still get this error: `Error: \\?\D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\scrypt\build\Release\scrypt.node is not a valid Win32 application.`

Comment: Sorry man i can't install the required dependencies instead of you. Please, be aware that I do this in my spare time for free. So maybe you need to pay some professional support service if this is not enough for you. You can find all the required information following the links in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were a support engineer. The point I was trying to make is that I could install the dependencies myself but a managed service should be able to handle this stuff. Even better, if done correctly it would install the modules for you, not a big deal to create a script to do it.

Comment: Are you sure that you are on the right forum? I have no idea what type of acc you have with Azure, but I am not their support engineer and this is not an official Azure support platform for sure. I know that Stackoverflow is on their community support page but based on your expectations you are on the wrong place. Which is quite suprising based on your reprutation on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Eddy this site is recommended by many external sites for support in the form of questions and answers. We are not affiliated with any of these sites, so we are relying on the good will of people to provide answers with their own experience.